# Align a paragraph in html : middle or center

Tags: html

In the development of html web pages. What is the difference between :

- align="middle"
- align="center"

Comment: Don't do it. [**Use CSS**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align)

Comment: Just because of this question quality, i'll include a link to **w3schools**! https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_div_align.asp Google it next time

Comment: @AlonEitan I agree with you in principle, but actually there is no reference to `middle` in the numerous literature that I've looked at from this, including your W3Skouls link (and even my own link to MDN). I remember I used to use middle many *many* years ago and believe it was associated with older versions of HTML, such as HTML3. As far as I can tell there is now no difference between `center` and `middle` ...

Comment: @Martin I recommend in that case to use CSS as you suggested, and if something is not documented then it might be unofficial property with limited support that should not be used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Historicaly speaking, ***middle*** refers historically to being in the centre of *both* vertical and horizontal dimensions. I remember (vaguely) using this syntaxing back on HTML3 and the *very* early days of web design, particularly for centering table cell contents both in the X and Y planes.

As far as I can tell `middle` can now only be used in inline `<table>` construction code, and is the same output as center.

***center*** refers more often (but not always) to the horizontal plane *only*, so horizontally centres an element such as horizontally centering text in a column.

Nowerdays (ie since 2006) if `middle` is a valid value at all, it is simply another word for `center` and wll be silently converted by the HTML renderer.

## BUT

Generally speaking, as of 2017 (*and several years beforehand!*) you should not be using these sort of construction syntaxes in HTML at all, instead passing all this technical layout construction stuff [to **CSS**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align)).